# NSManagedObject manipulation after deletion

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have the following questions about managed objects manipulation after deletion:

1. Can a deleted managed object still be used before the commit? After commit?
2. Can a deleted managed object be re-inserted without creating a new one (with insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the deleted object. The object is not going to be persisted with out reinserting it onto the context.

To reinsert the object, you should use `insertObject:` of `NSManagedObjectContext`.

```
insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext: method always creates the new object.
```

Comment: I can be wrong, but if use properties of deleted managedObject you will gain exception, no?

Comment: If you don't commit the context then you can access them. If you commit the changes to the context after deleting the object from context then it will be in fault state. You can insert the object and change the state.